# Execution of code which is inside ng-if when it is false

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

Imagine I have code like this:

```
<span>Do you like  bananas?</span>
<input type="radio" ng-model="likeBananas" name="likeBananas" value="yes">
<input type="radio" ng-model="likeBananas" name="likeBananas" value="no">
<div ng-if="likeBananas === 'no'">
    <label>Tell us why?</label>
    <textarea ng-model="whyNot" ng-required="likeBananas === 'no'"></textarea>
</div>
```

The idea is: if user don't like bananas, `<textarea>`with explanation is required. If user like bananas, of course it is not required and it's not shown to user. Because mandatory ot this field is dynamic, I used `ng-required="likeBananas === 'no'`, but question is - do I really need it? Maybe simple `required` can do a job? Because, when `ng-if` is false, content of `div` should not be present in HTML. General question is - how Angular execute code inside elements with `ng-if`s directive, *from top to bottom* or *from bottom to top*? In first case, code inside elements with `ng-if`s when it's false should not be executed and, with case above, `ng-required` is not calculated when `div` is not present and maybe isn't needed. I hope you would help me with my doubts - thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? Change it to `required` and see if your form is $valid when `likeBananas === 'no'` is true. (put this in your html: `{{myForm.$valid}}').
To test your other hypothesis, add an `ng-init` to the textarea that calls a function which logs a message to the console with `console.log`. Make sure `likeBananas` is anything but 'no' for the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should use simply `ng-required=true` into a `ng-if` directive (in your case), because this directive behavior is `removing/adding` **from the DOM** the elements in it when the condition switch.

Thus, if `likeBananas !== 'no'`, the elements

```
<label>Tell us why?</label>
<textarea ng-model="whyNot" ng-required="likeBananas === 'no'"></textarea>
```

are not included in the DOM, so the `ng-require=true` is not compiled.

Answer (score -1):

please have a look here in the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fqoUbTXICDv0nNQe9aOL?p=preview

by making a `form` element, you can check it's validity, by doing:

```
Is the form valid? {{banana.$valid}}
```